# Toggling through a chain of styles with pure HTML + CSS (no JavaScript)

Tags: html, css

Everybody knows the trick with toggling by click between 2 styles of `<label>` via `<input type="checkbox">`.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked+label {
  background: green;
}

label {
  background: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<label for="toggle"></label>
```

But what if you want to toggle through a chain of styles?

For example: *click 1 => CSS 1, click 2 => CSS 2, click 3 => CSS 3,  click 4 => CSS 1... etc.*

Is it possible with HTML + CSS only?

**UPD**: Yes, it is. My approach is below. But is it possible to make the solution simpler?

```css
input, label {
  display: none;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#toggle1:checked~div {
  background: red;
}

#toggle2:checked~div {
  background: yellow;
}

#toggle3:checked~div {
  background: blue;
}

#toggle1:checked~div [for=toggle2],
#toggle2:checked~div [for=toggle3],
#toggle3:checked~div [for=toggle1] {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="toggle" id="toggle1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="toggle" id="toggle2">
<input type="radio" name="toggle" id="toggle3">

<div>
  <label for="toggle1"></label>
  <label for="toggle2"></label>
  <label for="toggle3"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: CSS is for styling. JS is for functionality. You shouldn't expect functionality related things from CSS alone.

Comment: It seems very difficult(if not impossible) even if it is possible it will take a very long way to make it; lengthy + inefficient.

Comment: @MohammadUsman, you are right in general, but in some cases CSS tricks can be less lengthy and more efficient than JS solutions.